# flutter Null check error: did not show file and line number

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Flutter ran into error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was:
```

In Visual studio code, the above message did not show file and line number.

Comment: does `flutter clean` help? if fails can you include include more details/snippet